# TableView doesn't refresh when created programmatically

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloaddata

I programmatically created a UITableView that fills with data that I fetch from an API. When I fetched the data asynchronously, I try to update my table view—but it does not update.

I first create a UITableView within my UIViewController. The data I am trying to load does load correctly, it just comes in after the initial view has loaded. When I try to refresh my data by doing reloadData(), nothing happens.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Creating my controller:

```
class SpotifyTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

//table view programmatically added
let tableView = UITableView()

var safeArea: UILayoutGuide!

var playlists = [PlaylistItem]()

@objc func handleRefreshControl() {
   // Update your content…
    tableView.reloadData()
   // Dismiss the refresh control.
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
   }
}
```

My viewDidLoad() function

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
     view.backgroundColor = .white      
     let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
      tableView.refreshControl?.addTarget(tableView, action:
                                          #selector(handleRefreshControl),
                                          for: .valueChanged)
    tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl

    self.loadPlaylists(accessToken: 


    setupTableView()
}
```

Setting up the table:

```
func setupTableView() {
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
  }

func loadPlaylists(accessToken: String) {
       .... make API call and retrieve data 

       let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       // update UI
                    ...

                    }
                   }

                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                   return
            }
           }
       })
       task.resume()

    self.tableView.performSelector(onMainThread: Selector("reloadData"), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you set tableview delegates after you reload tableview you must add tableview.reloadData() in setupTableView() in last line of code or you can first call setupTableView() and after that call self.loadPlaylists(accessToken:

```
super.viewDidLoad()
 view.backgroundColor = .white      
 let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
  tableView.refreshControl?.addTarget(tableView, action:
                                      #selector(handleRefreshControl),
                                      for: .valueChanged)
tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl

setupTableView()
self.loadPlaylists(accessToken:
```

or

```
func setupTableView() {
view.addSubview(tableView)
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.reloadData()
}
```